# cannot parse String with Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string formatted as below:

```
source1.type1.8371-(12345)->source2.type3.3281-(38270)->source4.type2.903..
```

It's a path, the number in () is the weight for the edge, I tried to split it using java Pattern as following:

```
[a-zA-Z.0-9]+-{1}({1}\\d+){1}
[a-zA-Z_]+.[a-zA-Z_]+.(\\d)+-(\\d+)
[a-zA-Z.0-9]+-{1}({1}\\d+){1}-{1}>{1}
```

hopefully it split the string into fields like

```
source1.type1.8371-(12345)
source2.type3.3281-(38270)
..
```

but none of them work, it always return the whole string as the field.

Comment: i dont get it, what is expected result? and your string ends with `...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want `String.split("->")` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)). This splits on the symbol `->` and returns an array containing the parts between `->`.

```
String str = "source1.type1.8371-(12345)->source2.type3.3281-(38270)->source4.type2.903..";
for(String s : str.split("->")){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output

```
source1.type1.8371-(12345)
source2.type3.3281-(38270)
source4.type2.903..
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you want to split at the `->`'s. So you could use something like `str.split("->")` If you were more specific about why you need this maybe we could understand why you were trying to use those complicated regexes